# How should stateless oAuth2 social login be implemented for a REST API - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, authentication, jwt, google-oauth

My aim is to have a login page on my Frontend, after logging in getting a JWT from the backend to authenticate on further requests.

I want to add a Google login option aswell, but after playing around with the oAuth2 client in spring, it won't work without it being stateful with a JSESSIONID cookie.

Is there a way, or a general conception on how to implement stateless oAuth2 social login alongside my own JWT Authentication implementation?

I tried changing the state management in the spring security filter chain configuration but it didn't work.

I expect to get some kind of token, to return in to the frontend and use it to authenticate on further requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login is an OAuth2 client concern and requires a state to store tokens. This state usually is sessions if the client is on the server and local-storage if it is in the browser (app with a framework like Angular and an OAuth2 client lib like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client), look for equivalents if using another framework).

The later is not the trend which is to hide tokens from the browser with an intermadite client on the server (see [BFF](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) in my tutorials)

If your client is configured to allow login from several OpenID Providers, the resource server (your stateless REST API) must accept access tokens from all of those issuers, and if you want to configure it with JWT decoders, then all OPs must emit JWTs (Google probably won't).

Also, if you want to setup some role based access control, user roles management will be exploded across OPs.

An option to avoid this multi-tenancy caveats is to use a façade for all OPs: a single authorization server with identity federation. Almost all OIDC Providers can do it (Keycloak, Auth0 and Amazon Cognito are just samples). You're then back to standard single tenant scenario which is much simpler with Spring Boot.

I expose quite a few OAuth2 scenarios in [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) and almost all are multi-tenant ready. Only those involving introspection aren't (required with opaque tokens like Google will probably deliver).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just realised my whole approach was wrong. Your previous answers on previous questions from different users also helped.

Comment: Glad all of it helped. I'm sometimes wondering if the time I spend trying to explain OAuth2 concepts is of any help to anyone...

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a similar problem. I could only find examples that relied on a JSESSIONID cookie. Additionally, I couldn’t find any best practices or recommendations on how to implement JWT authentication with `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`.

Eventually, the solution I came up with was a combination of Auth0 as a provider and a custom `successHandler`. Auth0 handles the authorization and provides a token to the application on a successful login. The custom `successHandler` parses the Authentication, extracts ID token, and sends redirect to the application UI with the token as a request parameter. The UI persists the token on a client side and uses it to authenticate with the backend API.

WebSecurityConfig (uiRedirectUri - configuration property):

```
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
...
http.getConfigurer(OAuth2LoginConfigurer::class.java as Class<OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>)
            .successHandler(SuccessfulAuthenticationHandler(uiRedirectUri))
...
```

SuccessfulAuthenticationHandler (extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler):

```
override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(
        request: HttpServletRequest?,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authentication: Authentication?
    ) {
        val user = (authentication as OAuth2AuthenticationToken).principal as DefaultOidcUser
        val idToken = user.idToken

...

        val targetUrl = uiRedirectUrl + "?token=" + idToken.tokenValue
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl)
```

Comment: You should read [the intro](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#12-client-vs-resource-server-configuration) to the tutorials I linked. "Stateless authentication" is antinomic: being authenticated is a state (this state can be stored in a JWT but clients have to store that JWT somewhere). resource servers can be stateless (and usually are). Clients can't be. Also, it is not recommended (at all) to use ID tokens as access tokens https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens#:~:text=Do%20not%20use%20ID%20tokens,application%20making%20the%20authentication%20request.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the answer to clarify the initial goal regarding 'stateless'.

Comment: Regarding ID tokens: you are right, I assumed that ID tokens should not be used only with external APIs. However, it seems like ID tokens should also not be used to authenticate with my backend application. I will do additional research to improve the answer.

Comment: A request authorized with a JWT is sent from a client to a resource server. One side can't be stateless: the OAuth2 client which stores tokens (in session if it is on the server, or maybe local storage if it's a JS application configured as OAuth2 client). The other side, resource server, can (and usually is). **A request sent from a browser to a Spring application configured as client (conf contains login) is not OAuth2**: it is secured with sessions, not tokens.